# Dynamic data in values.yaml file

Tags: yaml, helm3

I am trying to find a way to populate `values.yaml` with values I get from a DB tables.

I have `values.yaml` with values like this:

```
...
my_image:
  repository: my_repo
  replicaCount: 1
  tag: latest
  name: my_name
...
```

In my `template.yaml` file  I have  this:

```
...
  - image: "{{ .Values.my_image.repository }}:{{ .Values.my_image.tag }}"
...
```

I can create a json or yaml file from the query result.
I know that I can not populate the  `values.yaml` without using tpl. But I am not sure how to?
Is my only option to recreate the `template.yaml` every time?

Is there a way to generate `tagvalues.yaml` with a map of tags?  And use it like this in `values.yaml` file:

```
...
my_image:
  repository: my_repo
  replicaCount: 1
  tag: tagvalues.tag
  name: my_name
...
```